# High Collinearity Problem about XGBoost

Tags: boosting, multicollinearity

From my understanding of XGBoost, if two features have high collinearity, it will choose only one as a more important feature, while the importance of another feature will be very low. However, from my recent practice, it didn't show this. For example, from the figure below, PD and ED should have extremely high collinearity. However, the importance of ED is still very high from the importance graph. Still, when we look at the dependence plot, it shows a horizontal line for ED. Does it mean that the high collinearity problem is still not an issue in this model?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Currently, there is no figure showing correlation between the two variables. Maybe you can add one?

Comment: I have added a graph by simple multiple regression in SPSS, which demonstrates that Population/sq.km and Employment/sq.km have really high VIF (more than 200). It shows that they have a serious collinearity problem.

Comment: It doesn't have to choose only one.  It will choose a feature to make it's split and typically once you use a feature to split then the other feature has no new information since they are correlated.  Multicollinearity isn't a problem if your cross validation is fine with both features.  If you find a subset where your kfold or whatever is better then just use that.  Multicollinearity isn't a deal breaker with trees.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!